# How to apply a style to Object Text with an OLE inside

Tags: ibm-doors

I wanted to apply a style, strikethrough in this case, to the object's text, but I have encountered some problems for when the attribute contains an OLE Object.

Doing `obj."Object Text" = richText obj."Object Text"""` does not work as it takes away the OLE.

`obj."Object Text" = richTextWithOle "{\\strike " o."Object Text" "}"` does not work because richTextWithOle does not accept a string as parameter, only attributes.

`obj."Object Text" = richText "{\\strike " o."Object Text" "}"` stops Doors from responding, probably with no recover, as I waited like 5 minutes, from a small module with a single OLE, before force closing the instance.

Is this actually possible? If so, is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would take a small step back and have a look at what you may try to achieve in the end. If you want to mark requirements according to their state, I would suggest to use a separate attribute, which shows the actual validity of an object (e.g. "valid", "invalid", "tbd" or something along those lines) and not strike through the Object Text.

The other issue, that I would have is the "coarseness" of your requirements, which may result in a better separation between a textual requirement and a picture requirement or diagram, that illustrates something in more detail. Maybe the first step would be to clean up the requirements, i.e. to have them separated in a certain way, which also would make your strike-through issue more manageable.

Let me know, if that helped you. If not, maybe you actually have to build a DXL Script, which for example parses the content of an Object Text and goes through the rich text tags and handles them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about splitting text and image in 2 object, but simply because the object has been sent to the suppliers, so a new object might seem a new requirement, so that needs to be clarified. Multiply that x500, if not more, and you understand it's not possible. The objects are already marked with another attribute, it's just a visual thing, also for our custom Word export. I tried researching about highlighting the text, which is possible with DXL, and have the system type the style keyboard shortcut. Is there a way to make Windows, or Word VBS do that?